# ReflectionTypeLoadException in Simple.Data using PostgreSql

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, system.reflection, simple.data

I am trying to open PostgreSQL connection but getting ReflectionTypeLoadException while opening connection.

Please help me out to solve this problem by providing code or let me know how to remove this exception.

Code  i am using so far is below:

```
  **/* Connection String 
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="superuserDatabase" value="postgres"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear/>
         <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
           invariant="Npgsql"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server"
            type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
     </system.data>
     <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Simple.Data.Properties.Settings.DefaultConnectionString"
          connectionString="host=localhost;port=5432;database=SimpleData;user                                                                     id=postgres;password=P@ssw0rdsa;pooling=false"
           providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="Test"
          connectionString="host=localhost;port=5432;database=SimpleData;user    id=postgres;password=P@ssw0rdsa;pooling=false"
          providerName="Npgsql" />
     </connectionStrings>
   </configuration>**
   */
```

I am getting following exception when trying to open connection in POSTGRESQL
var namedDb = Database.OpenNamedConnection("Test").Demo.All();

**ReflectionTypeLoadException**

Comment: Thanks & Regards,
Vishal Patel
vishalmg@ymail.com
vishvaghasia123@gmail.com

Comment: Do you really have all those spaces between "user" and "id" in the connection strings? Oh - and are you sure there's not more than just a single word for the error?

Comment: no, i did not keep space ..Error is "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

Comment: And what did the LoaderExceptions property say?

Comment: couldn't find anything on that Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ReflectionLoadTypeException is most often caused because the DLLs you're using aren't up to date so the dependency chain fails. Use nuget to update your project with the latest DLLs. v0.16.2.2 of the PostgreSql provider requires

- Simple.Data.Core (≥ 0.12.2.2)
- Simple.Data.Ado (≥ 0.12.2.2)
- Npgsql (≥ 2.0.11)

(via Mark Rendle) Try explicitly installing 0.16.2.2 of Simple.Data.Ado first, then installing the Postgres package.